# XMLHttpRequest in browser open is not a function. not because lowercase

Tags: javascript, java, web

I create an HTML file and try to connect it to JAVA back-end via AJAX. I use JAVAseverlet. however, the send request part seems has some problem. in the browser, it shows xhr.open()； is not a function. the answer to this question is usually because of the UPPercase Open, while mine is not. I don't know why. anyone helps. thanks!!

```js
function ftn_button_clicked(){
      xhr = new createXHR();
      xhr.open("GET", "/PointGenerate.java", true);
      xhr.send();
      xhr.onreadystatechange = ajaxComplete;
}
function ajaxComplete(){
      if(xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200){
      document.getElementById("txt1").innerHTML.value = xhr.responseText;
      var num = xhr.responseText;
      window.alert("good");
       }
}
    
function createXHR(){
      if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
}else{
       xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
       //window.alert("1111");
}
}
```

Comment: you haven't included the part of your code that calls createXHR nor the part that tries to call xhr.open - in fact, the code you've shown is probably the least helpful to your question

Comment: `xhr = new createXHR();` since `createXHR` method doesn't return anything, `xhr` will always be `undefined`, hence you can't call `xhr.open(..)`
. Return the newly created `XMLHttpRequest` object or the `ActiveXObject` in the `createXHR()` method

Comment: Try to re-create the issue in a plunker or jsfiddle and share the link in your question. It will be helpful for others to help you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problems I see at a glance:

1. `createXHR` is a function, not an object, so you shouldn’t be using the `new` keyword.
2. `xhr` is not returned from `createXHR` (i.e. it’s returning `undefined`).

Also, you don’t need to check for `ActiveXObject` anymore. IE has supported `XMLHttpRequest` for a while (and it’s being replaced by Edge anyway).

Here's a quick (untested) rewrite (sorry, I couldn't resist):

```
function ajax(url, data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
            if(xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.staus < 400) {
                if(xhr.readyState === 4) {
                    resolve(xhr.responseText);
                }
            } else {
                reject();
            }
        }

        xhr.open(data ? 'post' : 'get', url, true);
        xhr.send(data);

    });
}

function ftn_button_clicked() {
    ajax('/PointGenerate.java').then((responseText) => {
        document.getElementById('txt1').innerHTML.value = responseText;
        plotrandom(responseText);
        window.alert('*Sign*, much better!');
    });
}
```

Comment: Your points are the exact problems that I have. It works! Thanks a lot, dude.

Comment: Glad to hear it. It would help me out if you would accept the question.